# How to write a Custom UILabel Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

In my project there is a huge number of `UILabels` available for each screen that's why I have created one separate class for `UILabel` and I want to set all label properties in that class.

But label properties and label also not adding in my `MainViewController`.

My code:

CustomLabel:

```
#import "CustomLabel.h"

@implementation CustomLabel

- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self){

        [self setupUI];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setupUI {

    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}
```

MainViewController:

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "CustomLabel.h"

@interface MainViewController ()
{
    CustomLabel * mainLabel;
}

@end

@implementation SampleViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    mainLabel = [[CustomLabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 150, 100, 35)];
    [self.view addSubview:mainLabel];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`awakeFromNib` doesnt get called if you just alloc/init it yourself afaik, you need to put that `[self setupUI];` in the init method that you should override

```
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   if(self){

      [self setupUI];
   }
   return self;
}
```

Comment: i am not understand clearly please tell me with some code because i am very new for this technology

Comment: replace awake form nib method with the updated answers code

Comment: hmm strange, does the label show up at all? or is it just not coloured correctly?

Comment: it's not adding in my mainView controller see i have updated my code with ur code but no result

Comment: can we set Labels frames also in CustomLabel class? i mean i don't want to set each label frame in my main class is it possible?

Comment: oh, i was overriding the wrong init method, can try this one instead in the updated code. The accepted answer i guess would work, but its not exactly efficient since it would re-setup your labels every time there is a layout change which in unnecessary

Comment: yes, you could make your own init method that would call `initWithFrame` inside it and set it to whatever you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99670/discussion-between-krish-and-fonix).

Comment: unfortunately im at work and the network blocks access to the stackoverflow chat so i cant

Answer (score 1):

your label added successfully if you want to check then set some text for that.

i think you dont set any View for that label so awakeFromNib not call here 
for that you have to write code in layoutSubviews methods

```
#import "CustomLabel.h"

@implementation CustomLabel

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [self setupUI];
}

- (void)setupUI {

    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}

@end
```

Comment: can we set Labels frames also in CustomLabel class? i mean i don't want to set each label frame in my main class

Comment: yes for that you have to create class method in custom label like 
`+(id)getLabel
{
    CustomLabel *menu;
    menu = [[self alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 25, 250, 222)];
    [menu setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [menu setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    menu.text = @"hjh";
    return menu;
}`

and to use it in viewcontroller like `mainLabel =  [CustomLabel  getLabel];`